# Prevent space increasing between elements on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar in which there are certain `li` elements as an index, and on hover of each of the li elements, I have a specific image appearing 'over' the li elements (eg: `position:relative;top:-25px;`)

Let's say I hover over the first li element and the rollover images appears fine. However, the space between 1st and 2nd element increases while this hover is occuring. I am not able to understand why this is happening and I want to stop this from happening i.e. the image should appear over the `li` item without no spacing problem but only a simple rollover.

Here is a fiddle of the problem I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/PF35v/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use absolute positioning in this case, I usually do when dealing with images and top/side nav bars that are "glued" to one side of a screen. Alternatively, in situations in which I am set on using `relative` vs. `absolute` I use a little cheat....Here is what I changed in the above fiddle

```
 ul#nav a:hover+img {
 display: block;
 position:relative;
 top:-35px;
 margin-bottom:-48px;
 }
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/PF35v/9/

However, if your images are all different sizes, you would need to individually set up the `top` and `margin-bottom` positioning.

Comment: Thanks for help. I wanted my rollover images to appear over the corresponding list elements and not under each of the li elements on which the mouse is hovered. I tried to set the position to eg: top:-10px to come over the li element on which the mouse is hovered, but I start getting fluttering. Any solutions for this?

Comment: They appear over each `li` from what I can tell...here is an updated fiddle with a black square image so you can see for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/PF35v/7/. I also started working on your sub-menu list. It was not displaying right because of the first two `li` elements of your side-menu `ul` were not styled

Comment: My bad seems like the fiddle didn't save my changes. 1 sec....OK you can take a look at the updated fiddle now

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the fiddle and it looks like working. I tried to do the same quickly in my website and didn't get proper results as I was expecting. Will try again today just as I reach home

Comment: let us know how it goes. It's really a principle so if you wanna share your a link to your website may be we can help see why it's not working there

Comment: I still am stuck with this. I really could use some help ;-/

Comment: I looked at your site and none of the links had negative bottom margins, which is what I suggested. Just as an afterthought though you may want to look into positioning background image of a link. Here is a quick fiddle demonstrating the technique you can use - http://jsfiddle.net/LB4TU/. You just need an image that's half transparent, half whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying for replying. I edited and used the hover event images as background images instead of modifying the DOM on hover and looks like it's working fine now. However, a little off-topic, if you notice the `personal` `li` item in the sidebar of harpreetsareen.com, the sub-menu that has to  appear is not appearing fine as per what I tried with your solution. Could you please have a glimpse and suggest how do I repair that? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

adding "position:absolute;" to ul#nav a:hover#first_id+img is stopping the LIs being pushed down (tried this on Chrome). Did you try this?

Comment: Can you also check if there's a solution to the fluttering I am getting here on one of the items. (third `li` item in the list)

Comment: I am not much epxrience with the front-end stuff but I had to ask if I do the absolute position for each of the items, it kind of starts feeling to me as hard-coded web page. By this I mean, I would have to manually keep the elements in my web page at positions (absolute positions) as they appear in my browser. Would this kind of absolute positioning be fine for the elements on the page and work across browsers/devices as well? Is this the correct way of doing it?